# Remove input field from but keep the value on cell

Tags: javascript, php, excel, export

I have a table where the user can insert value on input text field on every cell. Something like a grade table. I want to export the table using js. When i press export it exports the table but not the value in the fields.

How can i remove the input but return the value on the cell?

For now, the export receives the table throught table.innerHTML

```
var x = document.getElementById(el).rows;
var xls = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    xls.visible = true;
    xls.Workbooks.Add
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var y = x[i].cells;
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            xls.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = y[j].innerText;
        }
    }
    xls.Visible = true;
    xls.UserControl = true;
    return xls;`
```

How to get the value from y[j].innerText where there is an input?

Comment: Why use input fields at all? Why not use the attribute `contenteditable="true"`?

Comment: because it stored the data on mysql, it's a form.

Answer (score 0):

Found that one..

for every row on the first for loop i inserted

`var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input')`

and replaced

`y[j].innerText`

with

`xls.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = y[j].inputs[i].value;`

Now it exports the values only from the inputs